# Java: How do generic methods work?

Tags: java, generics

I have several types of `Objects` which I'm trying to count.  These objects are very different from one another, but the common feature is that they each have a `Enum` constant describing them.

For instance, `Day.getDayOfWeek()` member might return `DayOfWeek.THURSDAY`.  `Card.getSuit()` may return `Suit.SPADE`, `Dog.getBreed()` might return the enum constant `Breed.LABRADOR`, etc....

Now, let's say I have a `List<T>` of these objects (`List<Dog>`, `List<Card>`, etc...), and I want to count these objects based on their enum states.  Individually, I could do the following:

```
    public int[] getSuitCount(List<Card> cardList, int enumSize) {
        int[] array = new int[enumSize];
        for (Card card : cardList) {
            ++array[ card.getSuit().ordinal() ];
        }
        return array;
    }

    public int[] getDayCount(List<Day> dayList, int enumSize) {
        int[] array = new int[enumSize];
        for (Day day : dayList) {
            ++array[ day.getDayOfWeek().ordinal() ];
        }
        return array;
    }

    public int[] getBreedCount(List<Dog> dogList, int enumSize) {
        int[] array = new int[enumSize];
        for (Dog fido : dogList) {
            ++array[ fido.getBreed().ordinal() ];
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Although this would work, it's extremely repetitive.  The following is preferable:

```
    public int[] getEnumCount(List<T> itemList, int enumSize
                             SomeFunction GENERIC_FUNCTION()  ) {

        int[] array = new int[enumSize];
        for (Class<T> item : itemList) {
            ++array[ item.GENERIC_FUNCTION().ordinal() ];
        }
        return array;
    }
```

...the only problem is, `GENERIC_FUNCTION()` has a different name in each member it's invoked on.  Is there a way to represent generic functions?  When I say generic, I mean, is there a way that `GENERIC_FUNCTION()` can represent getSuit() or getBreed(), since they both return `Enum<?>`?

I would like to be able to pass `List<Card>` and  `Card.getSuit()` arguments into this function, and get the correct count.  I have hundreds of functions of this structure, so this is a very non-negligible optimization in terms of readability and maintenance.

**NOTE:  I cannot edit any of these classes at all.  The only thing I can do is use a generic function, if such a thing exists.**

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Java 8 (let's say Java 7), or just with generics, this is totally possible. The generics equivalent of a lambda, or a delegate function, is a functional interface with a single defined method you can call.

First define a functional generic interface that will give you a common method to call, and which you can override for each concrete type:

```
interface GetEnumFromType<S> {
  Enum getEnum(S item);
}
```

Now you call this in your counting method:

```
public static <T> int[] getEnumCount(List<T> itemList, int enumSize,
    GetEnumFromType<T> converter) {

  int[] array = new int[enumSize];
  for (T item : itemList) {
    ++array[ converter.getEnum(item).ordinal() ];
  }
  return array;
}
```

And finally you can call it by creating an anonymous class for each type which calls the actual "enum" method (or a concrete class if you use this in a lot of places):

```
int[] suitCounts = getEnumCount(cards, Suits.values().length,
    new GetEnumFromType<Card>(){
      public Enum getEnum(Card card) { return card.getSuit(); }
  });
int[] dayCounts = getEnumCount(days, DayOfWeek.values().length,
    new GetEnumFromType<Day>() {
      public Enum getEnum(Day day) { return day.getDayOfWeek(); }
  });
int[] dogCounts = getEnumCount(dogs, Breeds.values().length,
    new GetEnumFromType<Dog>(){
      public Enum getEnum(Dog fido) { return fido.getBreed(); }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda expression to do this conveniently, if you have a Java 8 compiler.

```
public int[] getEnumCount(List<T> itemList, int enumSize
                         Function<T, Enum<?>> enumGetterFunction) {

    int[] array = new int[enumSize];
    for (Class<T> item : itemList) {
        ++array[ enumGetterFunction.apply(item).ordinal() ];
    }
    return array;
}
```

`Function` is an interface similar to `Callable` or `Runnable`, but which takes one argument and returns a result. You can create a `Function` using lambda syntax (`(Dog d) -> d.getBreed()`), which means you can call `getEnumCount` like this:

```
int[] counts = getEnumCount(listOfDogs, Breed.values().length, (Dog d) -> d.getBreed());
```

or even shorter, by using a method reference (equivalent to the above):

```
int[] counts = getEnumCount(listOfDogs, Breed.values().length, Dog::getBreed);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, you should be able to use [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).